# Positive Sequence, convergent series, is the sequence decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If there is a positive sequence and the series of this sequence converges from n to infinity, 
must the sequence be decreasing? bounded or have a decreasing sequence? 
I'm not sure how to prove or give a counter example of each of these, help!

Comment: What are your thoughts? (Bounded is the easiest to answer)

Comment: "or have a decreasing sequence?" do you mean subsequence?

Answer (score 2):

$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ gives a non-monotonic sequence with $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.

We may build a counter-example with a positive sequence by taking $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ with $a_n$ being, instead, $\frac{1}{n}$ iff $n$ is a power of $2$.

On the other hand, if $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ is converging, then $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n = 0$ (otherwise the partial sums of the series cannot be a Cauchy sequence) and from every sequence converging to zero we may extract a monotonic subsequence by the [Erdos-Szekeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) or [Dilworth's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth's_theorem) theorem.
If $a_n>0$, the extracted subsequence is necessarily a decreasing subsequence.

Comment: Your $a_n$ is not positive.

Comment: @Thomas: go past the first line.

Comment: I did already. I was just wondering why you included this example as the question only adresses positive $a_n$. So the example is not addressing anything in the question.

Comment: @Thomas: It is just an introductory line, it serves the purpose of showing that there is a trivial counter-example if we drop the positivity constraint.